# background color does not work in outlook..How to make my table look good in email?

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have a table content to be emailed using a perl script. "background-color:#dddddd" doesn't seem to work in windows outlook. Email looks plain.

How to make my table look as i want?

Answer (score 0):

Some emails decide also to not show html content, but this is not your case.
first I would suggest you to use (took from quickstart guide cpan)

```
 use strict;
  use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
  use Email::Simple;
  use Email::Simple::Creator;

  my $email = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
      To           => '"Xavier Q. Ample" <x.ample@example.com>',
      From         => '"Bob Fishman" <orz@example.mil>',
      Subject      => "don't forget to *enjoy the sauce*",
      Content-Type => 'text/html'; 
    ],
    body => "This message is short, but at least it's cheap.\n",
  );
  sendmail($email);
```

look at [mail sender example](http://search.cpan.org/~jenda/Mail-Sender-0.8.16/Sender.pm#Sending_HTML_messages), we will not be able to help you if you don't put some code as an example